# Start nginx on boot with config in non-standard location

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to do something that I consider fairly simple... When Ubuntu boots, I want to start nginx using a config in a non-standard location (e.g. /home/ubuntu/foo/nginx.conf)

I've just installed that latest nginx (1.10.1) and I notice that it starts on boot and if I do `ps ax` I get a list of a bunch of worker process.

I haven't been able to find any standard way for it to not use its default config in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

I could copy the contents of my .conf file into the standard .conf file and that would solve the problem. I don't what to do that because mine is in source control in its location and it will be updated now and then.

I was thinking of adding an @reboot entry to crontab to stop nginx and then start it with the `-c` param so that it would pickup my config. However that feels like the wrong solution. i.e. 1. allow Ubuntu to start nginx 2. shut it down 3. restart it with a different config.

Anyone know the answer to this?

Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I haven't tested it, but try creating an override file: `sudo tee /etc/init/nginx.override <<< 'exec /usr/bin/nginx -c /home/ubuntu/foo/nginx.conf'. I think an override file should be able to replace the `exec` command, but I'm not sure.

Comment: That didn't work - thanks for the idea though @muru.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I eventually came up with was to delete the contents of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and replace it with a single include line that pointed at the config that was under source control:

`include /home/ubuntu/foo/nginx.conf;`